# Functions that satisfy the identity $f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) f\left(-\frac{y}{r}\right)=f\left(\frac{x-y}{t-r}\right)$

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations

I am looking for function(s) which satisfy the following property:

> $$f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) f\left(-\frac{y}{r}\right)=f\left(\frac{x-y}{t-r}\right)$$

I am not sure if there is any function which satisfies this property.

I thought that using an ansatz  like $f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)=\exp \left[g\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)\right]$ should help.
But I can't get any further.

Comment: What about constant functions ? Are $t,r$ fixed real numbers ?

Comment: looking for non trivial solutions

Comment: @DietrichBurde That constant function is either 1 or zero.

Comment: @onephys This is supposed to hold for all $x,y,t,r\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes, this concernes the above statement "I am not sure if there is any function which satisfies this property". So the non-trivial function $f\equiv 1$ will do.

Comment: I guess, for onephys this is a trivial function. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the three equations
$$\left\{\begin{align}
\frac{x}{t} = & z_1,\\
-\frac{y}{r} = & z_2,\\
\frac{x-y}{t-r} = & z_3.
\end{align}\right.$$
They can always be solved, except for some special values of the $z_i$ (e.g. $z_1=z_2=0$). This implies that the only solution is $f$ must be constant and equal either $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not specified in the question, so I'll suppose that the functions under consideration are functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and that the desired property should hold for all real $x, y, r, t$ for which both sides of the equality are defined.

If we set $y = 0$ and $r = t - 1$ we get $$f\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) f(0) = f(x)$$ for all $x, t$. Evaluating at $x = 0$ gives that either $f(0) = 0$ or $f(0) = 1$. The former case immediately implies that $f(x) = 0$, and the latter almost immediately that $f(x) = 1$. So, these are the only two solutions.